# How to handle column names with comma in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to modify my 'Energy Supply' column but is throwing an error!

```
import pandas as pd
energy= pd.read_csv('Energy Indicators_v1.csv' , engine ='python')
energy[('Energy Supply')] = energy[('Energy Supply')].apply(lambda x:x*1000000)
print(energy)
```

> KeyError: 'Energy Supply'

Can you guys help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: First of all check if your dataframe has column by using `print(df.columns)`

Comment: First thought is that your column has a leading or trailing space.  Sneaky spaces!  For example: ' Energy Supply'.  Note the leading space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove brackets.

```
energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply'].apply(lambda x:x*1000000)
```